# This is not a boarding card .... go to check-in for visa check and boarding card?

Tags: visas, tickets, ryanair

i just bought a Ryanair plane ticket from Marrakech to Milano-Bergamo, but I see on the ticket that this is not a boarding card and I need a visa. I'm a Moroccan passport holder  who lives in italy, so I have  an italian identity card and an unlimited residence permit, and actually I never needed a visa to travel to/from  Morocco/ Italy.
I traveled to Marrakech one month ago with a normal ticket ( with the QR code).
So now i have to go back to Italy.

I don't know why i received a boarding pass like that....
Can someone help  me, please?

Comment: You only get a boarding pass when you check in on the day that you actually travel.

Comment: Your Moroccan passport, togeather with your **residence permit**, is what you need to show. Note: An italian identity card, issued to non Italians, is **only** valid within Italy. The residence permit card, togeather 
 with your passport,  should be used for **any** cross border travel.

Comment: @MarkJohnson that sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is very common for that to happen, because the airline is required to verify that you *really* have what paperwork you claim to have - anybody could say he has such a card.
No worries, at check-in, someone will look at your card, and you’ll get your boarding pass.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to Ryanair's check-in desk and show your reservation as well as your EU National Identity Card to get the real boarding pass.

Ryanair will not issue boarding cards for extra-EU flights until they have verified that you have valid <strike>visa</strike> right to enter.

> but i see on the ticket that this is not a boarding card and i need a Visa

I don't know exactly where you can read this and with which exact wording, but don't worry. The airline is simply using the word "visa" in a generic way and both an ID card and a secondary EU passport will get you to Milan. You just show them at the desk

Comment: OP does not have an EU passport.  It will be necessary to show the foreign passport and the Italian residence permit.

Answer (score 2):

Your Moroccan passport, togeather with your **residence permit**, is what you need to show.

Note: An italian identity card, issued to non Italians, is **only** valid within Italy.

| Carta D'identita, issued to non Italians |
| --- |
| [image] --- Note the **NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO** (*not valid for travel abroad*) entry in the lower right corner area |

The residence permit card, togeather with your passport, should be used for **any** cross border travel.

---

**Sources**:

- [ITA-BO-04004, Identity card, Carta D'identita](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/ITA-BO-04004/index.html)

  - There is a second version of this document marked "NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO" ("not valid for travel abroad")